# How to link a paper-button to another Polymer page?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-2.x

I created a Polymer 2.0 app from the starter kit template in order to get to know the framework a little bit. I have a `paper-button` that should link to another page of the app. However, I still haven't figured out how to do so, since Polymer is loading pages dynamically via JavaScript rather than the browser just calling another one.

I also noticed something else strange: When I click a link in my `app-drawer`, the page changes automatically and the URL in my browser tab is being updated. However, when I hit refresh with that new URL in my address bar, I get a 404 error since the URL doesn't exist. So is there any way I can resolve this issue and link my button to another page?

This is my button:

```html
<paper-button id="buttonStartQuiz" on-click="startQuiz">
    go! <iron-icon icon="chevron-right"></iron-icon>
</paper-button>
```

And this is the JavaScript class that corresponds to the layout:

```javascript
class MyView1 extends Polymer.Element {

    static get is() { return 'my-view1'; }

    /* This method is the listener for the button click */
    startQuiz(e) {
        // Found this on a website, but doesn't work
        this.set('route.path', '/view-question');
    }

}

window.customElements.define(MyView1.is, MyView1);
```

I don't know if it's any useful, but here are my imports in case you need to know.

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is Polymer doesn't do that, some element (`app-route` which implement with Polymer) do that. The Polymer itself is the library that help you work with [custom element](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements) easier.

This behavior done by JavaScript and History API. See how to use it on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). An application like this, dynamically rewriting the current page rather than loading entire new pages its called a single-page application ([SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)).

Basically application like this have only one page (`index.html`). When you try to load from another path the server will cannot find it.

You can resolve this by config the server to serve every path you used with `index.html`. For development you can easily use `polymer serve` command from polymer-cli see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli).

To link to another page you can done by many ways:

=> Wrap your element with `<a>`:

```
<a href='/another-page'>
  <paper-button>...</paper-button>
</a>
```

=> Change `route` variable from `app-location`: in my-app.html

```
<app-location route='{{route}}'></app-location>
...
<paper-button on-click='changeRoute'>...</paper-button>

class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
  ...
  changeRoute () {
    this.set('route.path', '/another-page')
  }
  ...
}
```

If you want to do this in your file just import and use `app-location`.

=> Use History API

```
window.history.pushState({}, null, '/another-page');
// Notify to `app-location`
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('location-changed'))
```

Comment: I decided to use app routing and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your detailed and helpful answer!